# Enable Emmet for .tsx files on VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet, react-tsx

I'm using Visual Studio Code. How can I enable emmet on .tsx files?

I'd like a simple

```
.foo + tab
```

to be expanded to

```
<div className="Foo"></div>
```

However, nothing I tried seemed to trigger emmet with the desired behavior above.

Here's my VSC settings:

```
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",
        "typescript": "typescriptreact",
    },
```

Comment: Hi, the settings you have described in your question works fine for `.js` and `.tsx` file with `JSX` support. One reason it might not be working for you is, `"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "inMarkupAndStylesheetFilesOnly"` which should ideally be `"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always"` as was in my case.

Answer (score 33):

I set this in my VS Code user settings and it works as desired for `.tsx` files:

```json
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "typescript": "typescriptreact"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```json
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "typescript": "javascriptreact"
},
```

this is my setting, it can work well

Answer (score 3):

Open settings. here's a quick shortcut: for windows use `Ctrl + ,`  while on mac hit `Command + ,`

look for the key `includeLanguages`. Enable Emmet abbreviations in languages that are not supported by default. here's an example:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "typescript": "javascriptreact"
},
```

Adjust "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation" based on your needs (either use `Always` or `inMarkupAndStylesheetFilesOnly`)

In settings, it should be like this

`"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "Always"`

and Here's a screenshot that might be helpful

[image: Emmet settings]